# Google Cloud Storage serve content from www.example.com and also from example.com

Tags: dns, google-cloud-storage, cname

Is there any way to host an entire site on Google Cloud Storage? That is, map a bucket directly to a top level domain.

e.g. :- create a bucket called www.example.com and CNAME to www, then when the user visits www.example.com and also example.com,should serve the content directly from cloud storage

I am able to run www.example.com but not example.com

Any solution?

Comment: Did you try to create a bucket without the WWW and then create a CNAME record pointing to the A record?

Comment: The only workaround to use example.com is to point the A record to the IP resolved by c.storage.googleapis.com, but this is a bad idea as the IP may change and break setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host an entire site on Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731252/how-to-host-an-entire-site-on-google-cloud-storage)