# How to point both root and sub domain to Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've successfully created a static website hosted on Google Cloud Storage.

The bucket name is like: www.example.com

and my CNAME record for  www points to `c.storage.googleapis.com`

I've verified both the www and root domain with Google Webmaster Tools.

On Google Webmaster Tools I have the www set as the primary domain (I have no idea if that's relevant, but saw a reference to it on another post here) and it's important that I serve the site from the www subdomain and not the root.

I can reach www.example.com fine,but no matter what I try with my root domain I only get the `<NoSuchBucket>` error.

Point of information: My DNS is managed by Cloudflare. When I use Github pages to host static sites I typically point the root to the www with a CNAME record (and no A record at all because [Cloudflare allows CNAME flattening](http://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/)), but that does not work here.

I've tried pointing my root domain to the www with a CNAME record and tried pointing it to `c.storage.googleapis.com.`

The Cloud Storage website configuration [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration) for Step 2 says: "`For example, for example.com, the CNAME record contains the following information: www CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com`" but makes no mention of pointing the root domain, yet this must be a common requirement.

I realize I could create an additional bucket with the root domain and point it to the www in http, but it seems as though there should be a way to do this with DNS records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host an entire site on Google Cloud Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731252/how-to-host-an-entire-site-on-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing you can do on Google Storage side to point example.com root domain to www.example.com bucket. The only option is redirecting/forwarding example.com to www.example.com on your DNS provider:

Check these links for forwarding on the Cloudflare:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-pagerules-url-forwarding/

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-do-url-forwarding-with-CloudFlare-

Answer (score 4):

You could not access your bucket using the url that is different with your domain / subdomains. Evenso when you want to access using the url of your *root domain* `http://yourdomain.com/`to your bucket  `gs://www.yourdomain.com` or the other way around.

So here you must choose either use your bucket named as your *root* `gs://yourdomain.com` or your bucket named `gs://www.yourdomain.com`, if you choose the bucket of `www` using your `http://www.yourdomain.com/` then its fine as it explained on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration).

But if you prefer to use the url of your root domain `http://yourdomain.com/` to access your bucket `gs://yourdomain.com`, here you need to set the @ record of the domain  as an [*ALIAS/ANAME*](https://superuser.com/a/1046499/505363) that act as the same as when CNAME a subdomain when it points to `c.storage.googleapis.com`

> You might find that pointing CNAME of a root domain via @ Record
>   are not supported on your domain providers. To get out from this you can
>   consider to point your NAME SERVERS to a DNS provider who support the
>   ALIAS or ANAME. Please refer to [*this answer*](https://superuser.com/a/1046499/505363) for more detail.

You can try on [Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/), set a [Custom NameServers](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/yourdomain.com) for  [*yourdomain.com*](http://yourdomain.com/) and set its @ [DNS Record](http://viewdns.info/dnsrecord/?domain=yourdomain.com) as an [alias](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris#cname) to `c.storage.googleapis.com`. Serve *[your bucket](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/yourdomain.com/)* as [public-read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20162788/4058484) and named the same as its [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) (`gs://yourdomain.com`). You may find that it works just fine.

Comment: concerning the last paragraph, "CNAME records for the root domain are not supported"

Comment: For the most of domain providers we cannot "CNAME records to the root domain". Consider to point your NAME SERVERS to a DNS provider who support the ALIAS or ANAME. I have edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

my solution is:
 - I created a static website hosted on Google Cloud Storage, with bucket name like: www.mydomain.hu
 - Added a CNAME record at my DNS provider for www which points to c.storage.googleapis.com
 - Created a .htaccess file with he following content and uploaded  to the root directory of mydomain.hu/

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.hu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.hu/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

If you already have an .htaccess file, insert these four line of code to the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This solution another another stack exchange site worked for me

> 1) Use a CNAME record to set your www.example.com to forward to the true hostname.
>
> 2) To configure the naked domain, add a "Synthetic Record", and set up a "Subdomain Forward." In the subdomain text box, enter the @ sign and nothing else.
>
> 3) Select option to 'Forward path'. That should do exactly what you want.
>
> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78481/forward-naked-domain-with-url-path-for-my-google-domain

Comment: @geisterfurz007 added more description, thanks for the info

Comment: Thank you! I retracted the vote and removed my comment :)