# Is it possible to serve different static websites from the same Google Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, subdomain

I've got a bucket in Google Cloud Storage and I've got two static web sites inside.

1. /mybucket/dir1/...(static web site files)
2. /mybucket/dir2/...

I've got two subdomains:

1. app.domain1.com
2. app.domain2.com

Is it possible to use the 1st sub-bucket for the 1st subdomain, and the 2nd sub-bucket for the 2nd subdomain?

I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236186/2833774 But not sure if I correctly understand if GCS has limitation about this or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done on the way you describe, instead you will have to use one bucket for the domain and [one bucket per subdomain](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#tip-subdomain).

First, you create a bucket whose name must be the same as the domain you point to. Then, you can validate it with a [CNAME record](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#tutorial-content).

After all that process, you can then create a second bucket with the subdomain name (because you verifed the domain name in the step before)